# How can I delete my account at this part, and this part only, of the SE network?

Tags: discussion

How can I delete my account at this part, and this part only, of the SE network?

Answer (score 1):

https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/contact

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to hear you would like to delete your account.

To delete your account, please [follow the instructions in the Help Center](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/help/deleting-account).